# Lightning component client-side controller in Flow Action - Error "invoke method"

Tags: salesforcedx

getting the following error message while using the code found [here][1]:

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:availableForFlowActions" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recId" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
          "recordId": component.get("v.recId"),
          "slideDevName": "related"
        });
        navEvt.fire(); 
        
    }
})
```

**Design:**

```
<design:component>
     <design:attribute name="recId" label="Id of the record" />
    
</design:component>
```

**Error:**

> Error Occurred: We can't execute this action. Ask your admin to check
> that the "c:Redirect" Lightning component's client-side controller
> includes an "invoke" method and that My Domain is enabled and deployed
> for your org.

As I'm not a developer I don't have any idea how to use "invoke" as mentioned by the error message.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the method name from init to invoke and change component also and this error should be fixed:

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:availableForFlowActions" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recId" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.invoke}" />
    
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    invoke: function(component, event, helper) {
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
          "recordId": component.get("v.recId"),
          "slideDevName": "related"
        });
        navEvt.fire(); 
        
    }
})
```

probably you don't even need a aura:handler look at this (and I also guess, that the aura:handler will call the method a second time - so try to delete it and look if it still works)
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:availableForFlowActions/documentation

Hope I could help you,

Bernhard